# How to make round TextView with text inside around round ImageView?

Tags: android

All the result I've checked are related to:

1. Using a `<shape>` and `<stroke>` so the final result will have some sort of border. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655264/how-to-add-a-shadow-and-a-border-on-circular-imageview-android) is not what I'm looking for.
2. Using a transparent round image as a background of my `TextView`.
3. Using a `<layer-list>` like so:

   `<item android:drawable="@drawable/android_launcher"/> 
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/imgview_round"/>`

where **android_launcher** is a `.png` image and **imgview_round** is an `xml` file where are defined `<shape>` with **ring** shape and `<stroke>` with **width** of 8dp.

The result I expect to be is:
[image]

The `TextView` is not obligaratory, it could be anything that can contain text and has some background.

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532633/how-to-make-ui-with-round-image-and-round-text-also-add-ratting-icon-on-same-ci) but it's for **iPhone**, I'm looking for an android solution.

Comment: maybe is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308822/how-to-render-text-on-path

You can use a canvas and draw curved text